# What's the point of this kind of macros?

Tags: c++, windows, macros

```
#define NAME(x) TEXT(x)
#define TEXT(quote) __TEXT(quote)   // r_winnt
#define __TEXT(quote) quote         // r_winnt
```

The above is from winNT.h, isn't `NAME("Virtual Cam")` the same as `"Virtual Cam"`,what's the point to use this macro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__TEXT` macro expansion is selected based on whether `UNICODE` flag is defined or not. If not it just expands to `quote` else it will append `L` to the quote so that it becomes `L"Virtual Cam"` . This string is interpreted as a wide char string.

Comment: Is `L` in `L"Virtual Cam"` a native syntax of C++ or defined in some header files?

Comment: I think it's native C++ code, since one can write wchar_t* pwstr = L"Test";

Comment: the C++ ISO Standard referes to wchar_t as C native ;-). So L is not C++ native code, but C native code ;-)

Comment: The '`L`' prefix to a string or character literal is in *both* the C and C++ language standards - it's how wide-character literals are formed in the source.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if your system is #defined to use Unicode. Then it will automatically change the literal for you to be a wide literal instead of a char literal.

Comment: But I don't see that logic above,how does it happen?

Comment: Where “use Unicode” means “use UTF-16 encoded Unicode,” since that is the Unicode encoding best supported by Microsoft tools and APIs.